# Python, SQLAlchemy, Snowflake, existing column defaults - insert in existing table with an autoincrement or column default value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an existing table in Snowflake and I'd like to use SQLAlchemy to insert records into. This table has an autoincrement ID field and two timestamp fields that have a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). I'm mostly concerned with the autoincrementing ID field (the timestamps I can calculate and populate before inserting).

Reading around I see that there is generally a bit of a challenge getting autoincrement fields to be populated - the Snowflake documentation seems to avoid the subject of working with existing tables, and refers us to the method of specifying a `Sequence` in the model:

*From https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#auto-increment-behavior:*

> **Auto-increment Behavior**
>
> Auto-incrementing a value requires the Sequence object. Include the
> Sequence object in the primary key column to automatically increment
> the value as each new record is inserted. For example:
>
> ```
> t = Table('mytable', metadata,
>     Column('id', Integer, Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True),
>     Column(...), ...
> )
> ```

This doesn't help if the table already exists and `ID` is `AUTOINCREMENT`, however. Also creating a new sequence object for every autoincrementing ID field in the database feels a little heavy handed seeing as Snowflake should handle this nicely within the table.

**My question really is:**

Have you managed to use SQLAlchemy to insert records into an existing Snowflake table and get an existing `AUTOINCREMENT` or `IDENTITY START 1 INCREMENT 1` type of field to update? If so, how?

Do I *have* to create my tables in code through SQLAlchemy using a model (and using a `Sequence` for the `ID` field) if I then wish to be able to insert records into it using SQLAlchemy?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/answers on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use snowflake but it seems from the docs that autoincrement actually uses a sequence anyways: [optional-parameters, scroll to AUTOINCREMENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters).

So maybe a sequence already exists anyways?  Can you inspect/describe the table with some sort of commandline utility?

I use postgresql and I actually make sequences and then add them to the table so it doesn't seem that weird to me, postgresql's `autoincrement` also uses sequences implicitly anyways -- [DATATYPE-SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

I think you should be able to just insert without specifying an id and it will autoincrement the sequence either way.  Or add an object without an id to the session to commit.

Comment: I've tried digging around for some reference to the actual sequence name in Snowflake but not found anything - looks like it must be part of the table object and not directly accessible.
Inserting without providing an ID doesn't work unfortunately - I would have expected this to work, but looks like SQLAlchemy does interesting stuff with the insert command under the hood. 
Thanks for you comments though - unless anyone else chips in I think I'm just going to have to live with using explicit sequences for autoincrements (which, as you say, may not be particularly unusual).